# Where is wsdl file in WCF service

Tags: wcf, web-services, wsdl

I have created a WCF web service and locally when I access the wsdl file like (http://localhost/myservice/service.svc?wsdl it shows the wsdl file just fine.  I then uploaded it to my virtual server hosted by GoDaddy and when I call http://my ip address:myport/service.svc?wsdl the result is the page where it states "You have created a service".  This is the same page that displays when I call the same url but without the ?wsdl (http://my ip address:myport/service.svc).  How can I get at my wsdl file on the virtual server?  Why did this happen differently than my local machine?

Comment: Do you have same config file on the sever as you had on your development machine?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure that your config file in hosting environment allows retrieving the WSDL document. It should contain this:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="metadata">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And reference this behavior in your service configuration.

**Edit:**

Just to make it clear. With default WCF behavior, the WSDL file is nowhere. It is auto-generated and this auto-generation must be allowed.

Comment: Fine, this is auto generated but it must be getting saved somewhere, temporarily at least...

Comment: While it should be obvious, the behavior element needs to be closed. I am unable to edit post as it contains too few changes.