# Consuming C# SOAP webservices in JAVA

Tags: java, c#, web-services, client

I have few SOAP Webservices which are defined in C# as a different solution and I have a GUI Application built in JAVA.

Can anyone provide links to consume those webservices through Java Application with description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are creating the soap services with something like WCF? Then that means that you have some WSDL at the soap end-point.

Useful links: [Where is wsdl file in WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260708/where-is-wsdl-file-in-wcf-service)

[Working with WSDL](https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls/)

You could use [JAX-WS](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html) to autogenerate a java client out of the WSDL exposed by the soap services end-point (the underlying implementation is irrelevant whether it is on .Net or any other framework).